# Rails Querying with Time Objects, Not Returning Date-Specific Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay so I'm having trouble querying my Job table. What I'm trying to do is fill a calendar with jobs corresponding to their respective dates. In my snippet I'm using the gem pry. With my current logic (line 28 in console) I'm aiming to search my jobs table where it will return all jobs on the same day. Right now when I render the [calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kiLC.png) as is every date is filled with all 5 Job objects. When I pry with what you see in the console I get the first 3. The first 3 all have the same created_at date but I don't know why it returns those when I'm asking for just one in the console's case.

FYI:
@calender_days is an array filled with Time objects format ex "2018-05-16 08:30:00 -0400"

Let me know if you guys need anymore information and thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: to clarify. I don't see why I'm getting 3 objects with dates 16th 22nd and 16th when I search with a Time object where the date is the 16th.

```html
    21:         <% 5.times do %>
    22:           <tr>
    23:             <% 7.times do %>
    24:               <td>
    25:                 <% date = @calender_days[count] %>
 => 26:                 <% binding.pry %>
    27:                 <u><%= date.strftime('%d') %></u><br />
    28:                 <% @jobs.where(:datetime == date.day).each do |job| %>
    29:                   <%= job.name %><br />
    30:                 <% end %>
    31:                 <% count += 1 %>
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x6fc59a0>>)> @jobs.where(:datetime == Time.new("2018-05-16 08:30:00 -0400"))
  Job Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs"
=> [#<Job:0x74f20b0
  id: 1,
  name: "Sweep Floor",
  datetime: Wed, 16 May 2018 08:30:00 EDT -04:00,
  created_by: 1,
  client_id: 9,
  notes: "Get under couch",
  workers: "3",
  created_at: Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:49 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:49 EDT -04:00>,
 #<Job:0x74f1fd8
  id: 2,
  name: "Wash Windows",
  datetime: Tue, 22 May 2018 11:30:00 EDT -04:00,
  created_by: 2,
  client_id: 10,
  notes: "Remove all spots",
  workers: "4",
  created_at: Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:49 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:49 EDT -04:00>,
 #<Job:0x74f1ee8
  id: 3,
  name: "Clean Kitchen",
  datetime: Wed, 16 May 2018 12:00:00 EDT -04:00,
  created_by: 1,
  client_id: 11,
  notes: "Wipe down cabinets",
```

Here are all my Job objects.

```html
[0] #<Job:0x65ef2a8> {
            :id => 1,
          :name => "Sweep Floor",
      :datetime => Wed, 16 May 2018 08:30:00 EDT -04:00,
    :created_by => 1,
     :client_id => 9,
         :notes => "Get under couch",
       :workers => "3",
    :created_at => Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:49 EDT -04:00,
    :updated_at => Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:49 EDT -04:00
},
[1] #<Job:0x65ec638> {
            :id => 2,
          :name => "Wash Windows",
      :datetime => Tue, 22 May 2018 11:30:00 EDT -04:00,
    :created_by => 2,
     :client_id => 10,
         :notes => "Remove all spots",
       :workers => "4",
    :created_at => Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:49 EDT -04:00,
    :updated_at => Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:49 EDT -04:00
},
[2] #<Job:0x65ec578> {
            :id => 3,
          :name => "Clean Kitchen",
      :datetime => Wed, 16 May 2018 12:00:00 EDT -04:00,
    :created_by => 1,
     :client_id => 11,
         :notes => "Wipe down cabinets",
       :workers => "7",
    :created_at => Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:50 EDT -04:00,
    :updated_at => Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:50 EDT -04:00
},
[3] #<Job:0x65ec4b8> {
            :id => 4,
          :name => "Dusting",
      :datetime => Wed, 16 May 2018 02:30:00 EDT -04:00,
    :created_by => 1,
     :client_id => 10,
         :notes => "Get the fans.",
       :workers => "8",
    :created_at => Sat, 19 May 2018 08:49:11 EDT -04:00,
    :updated_at => Sat, 19 May 2018 08:49:11 EDT -04:00
},
[4] #<Job:0x65ec3f8> {
            :id => 5,
          :name => "Dusting",
      :datetime => Thu, 03 May 2018 08:30:00 EDT -04:00,
    :created_by => 1,
     :client_id => 11,
         :notes => "TV Stand.",
       :workers => "4",
    :created_at => Sat, 19 May 2018 08:50:33 EDT -04:00,
    :updated_at => Sat, 19 May 2018 08:50:33 EDT -04:00
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Is the proper markup generated for your use case?

Comment: @NicoHaase I edited my post to clarify. Basically, in my pry I'm expecting to get only two Job objects because I'm querying with a Time object that has a date of 05/16 but I'm getting three; two of those objects are what I want because they are on the 16th but one is on the 22nd.

Comment: @GregoryJaros it must be the query. What happens if you run `where(datetime: DateTime.parse('2018-05-16 08:30:00 -0400'))`?

Comment: @Dimitry_N

I get one object now...


`[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x70437f0>>)> @jobs.where(datetime: DateTime.parse('2018-05-16 08:30:00 -0400'))
  Job Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."datetime" = ?  [["datetime", "2018-05-16 12:30:00"]]
=> [#<Job:0xd6d8530
  id: 1,
  name: "Sweep Floor",
  datetime: Wed, 16 May 2018 08:30:00 EDT -04:00,
  created_by: 1,
  client_id: 9,
  notes: "Get under couch",
  workers: "3",
  created_at: Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:49 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 17 May 2018 09:52:49 EDT -04:00>]`

Comment: @GregoryJaros so now you're getting that one job that matches the date as you wanted, correct? BTW, `where` returns a collection, if you change it to `find_by(datetime: ...)`, you will get the first record that matches this date.

Comment: @Dimitry_N Yes, it's one of the jobs I wanted but I want the query to return all objects with that date, which right now should be 3 where date is the 16th. I want a collection so that I can list them all. I just edited my post include all my job objects.

Comment: @GregoryJaros see my reply below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `Jobs.datetime` column type is `datetime` but you are trying to list items by date and not datetime. I think the following query should work:

`@jobs.where('DATE(datetime) = ?', Date.parse('Wed, 16 May 2018'))`

the `DATE(...)` part transforms the `datetime` into `date`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything. It adds an * to the next line.
`[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x6551928>>)> @jobs.where('DATE(datetime) = ?', Date.parse('Wed, 16 May 2018')
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x6551928>>)*`

Comment: @GregoryJaros forgot to close the paren. Updated

Comment: Nevermind! Just forgot a ')' on the end haha. That returned my 3 objects. Thanks you. I'm not sure I would have ever figured it out. I spent almost 4 hours trying to fix it myself up to this point.

Comment: Okay so now I'm having trouble adapting the solution to my embedded ruby code. Could you please translate the query?

Comment: @GregoryJaros what's the error? Show me here: https://appear.in/dimanyc

Comment: Sorry again, got it working. I just had to add to_s to the date like so `@jobs.where('DATE(datetime) = ?', Date.parse(date.to_s))`